# Open URL Into a View(MVC 3)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a problem with my Application I am using the MVC 3 with C# and VS 2010.

I have a old desktop application where in one form I added a control browser_Navigated for show one page where the user could add the credentials of yahoo for use one API.

Now my problem is that I don't know a lot of MVC3 then I am not sure how I can open one URL into a div
I try to use Ajax.ActionLink

```
public ActionResult GetAuthorizationLink()
{
   string s = "$('#divResultText').load('http:\\google.com')";
   return JavaScript(s);
}
```

I would like comment that where I will show the information is a pop up then I think that I can't open a popup inside another popup.

Thanks for any help, for obtain some idea for fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `<iframe>` to achieve that, especially if you are trying to load some external domain:

```
<iframe id="result"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="load">Load data</a>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#load').click(function() {
        $('#result').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That's amazing thank you very much. that is working good.
my Problem now is that I can show when I have for example "https" instead of "http"

Comment: I need do that because I need show a URL like this:"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=aobmsf" This is for use a Yahoo API then I need show the website where the user can add the credentials and accept use the API